# Evaluate until a regexp match is satisfied

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation, conditional, regular-expressions

How do you express the computation that, given a list of regular expressions, perform a replacement until one of them is satisfied.

For instance:

```
keys = {"x_millisec", "y", "z_milliseconds", "w_somethingelse", "a_Millisecs"}
pattern = ... (* it defines the named group `prefix' *)

With[ {key = ..., value = ... }, 
  Which[ 
    StringMatchQ[ key, pattern, IgnoreCase -> True],
    StringReplace[ key, { 
      (* remove the suffix `_millisecs' *)
      pattern :> StringTake[ prefix, StringLength[prefix] - 1] 
    }, IgnoreCase -> True ] -> Quantity[ value, "Milliseconds"] , 
    ...
    True, key -> value] 
  ]
] & /@ keys
```

This performs the replacement for a single pattern. Now I have a list of patterns for different units, such as seconds, millisecs, microsecs, nanosecs. I would to like to test the same string, `key', against each of those pattern, until one of them is satisfied. Is there a simpler way to proceed rather than extending the above redundant code?

Comment: This is literally what `SelectFirst` was designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've managed to reach at least a solution by using [scan](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html) to iterate over the patterns and adapting an [example for Perl users about the paper jam](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#759470019) from the product documentation. The idea is to split the process in two steps. The first step only creates a list of functions to be applied independently on each attribute of the dataset :

```
// ... for each key ...
scan = Scan [ 
  Module[{pattern, unit, repl}, 
    pattern = #["pattern"];
    unit = #["unit"];
    repl = StringReplace[key, pattern :> prefix , IgnoreCase -> True];

    If[repl != key, Return[ Quantity[ #, unit] & ] ] 
  &, patterns] 
If[scan =!= Null, scan, Identity]
```

Afterwards, iterate over each column/attribute of the data set/matrix and apply on each component the related function:

```
rules = %
Do[  
  data[[All, i]] = rules[[i]] /@ data[[All, i]],
  {i, Length[rules]}
];
```